# Changing a time format of an xml file using a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to change the formatting of a time in a file using a bash script.

Current time format:
08:05:00

Goal time format:
8-05

There are other timestamps I don't want to change in the file and every instance that I want to change is wrapped in xml:

time="current time format"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially you need examples of dates that you don't want to change and a complete excerpt of the XML-file.

Comment: at least you should post your input xml content

Comment: Are we to guess that you want to change every time that is *not* wrapped in xml?

Comment: So the format to change might be `<event name="foo", bar="baz", start="08:05:00", end="09:35:00">` or has it to be literally `time=`? And `<lecture><name>XML</name><start>08:05:00</start></lecture>` shouldn't be changed as well? Providing a minimal example with 2, 3 variations, including corner cases, would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an XML parser to solve this problem. I would do it in a language that comes with an XML parsing library and a date time parsing library. Python fits the bill

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import sys

tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])

# for each element with a "time" attribute, alter the format of the attribute value
for elem in tree.findall('.//*[@time]'):
    time = datetime.strptime(elem.get('time'), '%H:%M:%S')
    elem.set('time', time.strftime('%k-%M').lstrip())

# print the new XML to stdout
print(bytes.decode(ET.tostring(tree.getroot())))
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
<a>
<b time="08:05:00">
<c>text contains time 08:05:00</c>
</b>
<d foo="bar" time="19:54:55"/>
</a>
</root>

$ python3 alter_time.py file.xml > new.file.xml

$ cat new.file.xml
<root>
<a>
<b time="8-05">
<c>text contains time 08:05:00</c>
</b>
<d foo="bar" time="19-54" />
</a>
</root>
```

Error handling left as an exercise